# Block don't give output

Tags: blocks, template, magento-1

when i create block and insert like this,

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'reviewfororderproducts',array('template' => 'clarion/review.phtml '))->setData('data', $data);
```

it works fine `$block->toHtml()` returns a string with all html

but when i do like this

```
 $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Clarion_ReviewReminder_Block_Allproducts', 'reviewfororderproducts',array('template' => 'clarion/review.phtml '))->setData('data', $data);
```

i can't get the block, `$block->toHtml()` returns null

my block class is only extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`

```
class Clarion_ReviewReminder_Block_Allproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from your block? Otherwise you're asking why 1 plus something doesn't equal something else

Comment: Clarion_ReviewReminder_Block_Allproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    
}

Comment: If that's the only difference then why do you need it?

Comment: i don't have any code inside that

Comment: @RobbieAverill  i was having some functions, for debugging i deleted all the functions ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any custom code in your custom block and that block only extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` there is no point using a custom block.

It is not bad practice to use `Mage_Core_Block_Template` whenever you need to use a template.

### Debugging steps

I suggest you start in the `toHtml` method from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`.

Most of the time, empty HTML is caused by the fact that the module output is disabled in the backend but I don't think it's the case for you as you said it was returning null.

I suggest you add the following code in this method:

```
if ($this insteanceof Clarion_ReviewReminder_Block_Allproducts) {
    Mage::log($html);
}
```

Also add some logs to the `_toHtml` method of `Mage_Core_Block_Template` as weel as the `fetchView` method.

Comment: i will add some custom function in future ,  for now i have deleted all the functions to debug

Comment: @rephael  i m debugging now

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick see my edit for debugging